# Trailing zeros on an int Array

Tags: c++

I am trying to print out the contents of a four dimensional an Array of type int. However, the output is correct but there are some trailing zeros which i am not understanding in terms of their source. Anyone with a clue?

Source code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int i,j,k,m;

int nmArrays[5][5][5][5]= {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15},{16,17,18,19,20}};

for(i=0;i<5;i++){//subArray 0,0

    for(j=0;j<5;j++){//subArray 1,0

        for(k=0;k<5;k++){//subArray 2,0

            for(m=0;m<5;m++){//subArray 3,0

            cout<<nmArrays[i][j][k][m];
              }  
          }

    }

cout<<""<<std::endl;
}

getchar();

}
```

Output:

```
12345000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
678910000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1112131415000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1617181920000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: What output did you expect?  Your array has 625 entries ; you set non-zero values for only 20 of them.  So you should get 605 trailing zeroes in the output.

Comment: You have an array of 5*5*5*5 elements, but only initialize it with 4*5 explicit values.

Comment: The array contains 625 values and you only give 20. The rest will be set to zero by default.

Comment: You array has 625 items.  You initialize only 20 of them, but output them all....

Comment: Your array's size isn't 5 * 4. It is 5 * 5 * 5 * 5, i.e. 5 ^ 4.

Answer (score -1):

> Anyone with a clue?

What you are doing is initialize `4*5 = 20` elements (that in theory is a 2D matrix, but in memory it's always an array). 
While you have a `5*5*5*5` (`= 625 elements`) matrix.

So, all the positions you aren't initializing get filled by 0s.

Comment: You should edit your other answer, not delete it and post another one the same

Comment: @M.M that's a reason for downvote without explaining what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: I already explained what you did wrong. And the vote isn't mine.

Answer (score -2):

`{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15},{16,17,18,19,20}};` is a 2 D array, more specifically it is `5X5` matrix .

what you are looking for is `5x5x5x5` array.

**More insight:** Your first initializer list `{1,2,3,4,5}`, is used to fill the first subarray of size `5x5x5` and padded with zeros since you provided only first `5` entries, not `125` values.
Similar is the behaviour for the rest of the sub arrays.

For simplicity, Assume that your `5x5x5x5` array is `{ 5x5x5 subaary no 0,5x5x5 subaary no 1,5x5x5 subaary no 2,5x5x5 subaary no 3,5x5x5 subaary no 4}` . so correspondingly, your initializer lists are used for initialization of each sub-array padded with zeros.

Comment: no, it is a list of numbers separated by commas and delimited by braces.  `nmArrays` is the array and it is actually 4-dimensional. (well, insofaras we  describe an array of arrays as a 2-D array etc.)

Comment: @M.M, There is are no real intrinsic lists in c++, my friend. Think of How it is laid in memory!

Comment: A braced list is not laid in memory at all.  Only the declaration of `int nmArrays[5][5][5][5]` specifies a memory layout. Then the list of initializers is fitted to that memory layout. The list does not have any intrinsic layout.

Comment: @v78, You mentioned "Your first initializer list {1,2,3,4,5}, is used to fill the first subarray of size 5x5x5 and padded with zeros since you provided only first 5 entries, not 125 values. Similar is the behaviour for the rest of the sub arrays. "  How many elements will the second subArray take?

Comment: @user2841390, For simplicity, Assume that your ``5x5x5x5`` array is ``{ 5x5x5 subaary no 0,5x5x5 subaary no 1,5x5x5 subaary no 2,5x5x5 subaary no 3,5x5x5 subaary no 4}`` . so correspondingly, your initializer lists are used for initialization of each array.

Comment: @v78, on behalf of all who contributed thank you so much. Also let me take this opportunity to put it in simplest terms for the benefit of others, int nmArrays[5][5][5][5]; means that we have 5 rows of 5*5*5 columns. Thus row 0-4 of 125 elements each.